# Asyncio в потоке в приложение Pyqt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, asyncio

У меня есть приложение на pyqt5, внутри функции которого я создаю потоки через измененный класс, с целью остановки потока по желанию пользователя. После чего внутри потока используется asyncio, что вызывает конфликт.

```
def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    
    for i in range(0,requestsNumber):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.post(url, data = json.dumps(js), ssl=False)))
    return tasks

async def get_symbols(headers):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.text())

def startSsc(headers):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_symbols(headers))


class thread_with_exception(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        
   def run(self):
        #some code (основная функция для запуска в многопоточности)
        startSsc(head)

    def get_id(self):
 
        # returns id of the respective thread
        if hasattr(self, '_thread_id'):
            return self._thread_id
        for id, thread in threading._active.items():
            if thread is self:
                return id
  
    def raise_exception(self):
        thread_id = self.get_id()
        res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id,
              ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
        if res > 1:
            ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 0)
            print('Exception raise failure')

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self,code,end, Dialog):
        #some code

    def start(self):
         s = thread_with_exception(some_args)
         s.start()
         self.ap[i]=s

    def stop_all_tasks(self):
         for i in self.ap:
              self.ap[i].raise_exception()
              self.ap[i].join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(code,end,MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ошибка:

```
RuntimeError("There is no current event loop in thread '0'.")
```

решаю её следующими изменениями:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

тогда **периодически** возникает следующая проблема:

```
ClientOSError(22, 'Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно', None, 64, None)
```

Есть ли способ адаптировать этот код для выполнения выше описанной задачи?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: какую ошибку-то ?

Comment: @eri добавил ошибки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать asyncio внутри потока в приложении на pyqt5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363801/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-asyncio-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5)